# Find a positive integer $n$ (or prove that none exists) such that $\gcd(3^{n+1}-2,2^n-3) > 1$

Tags: number-theory

> Find a positive integer $n$ (or prove that none exists) such that $\gcd(3^{n+1}-2,2^n-3) > 1$.

The greatest common divisor here seems to be equal to one for most values (I checked up to $7000$), but I didn't see  an easy way of finding an $n$ for which this it is greater than $1$. How could we go about solving this?

Comment: Can you find $x,y$ such that $x(3^{n+1}-2) +  y(2^n-3) = 1$ for all  $n$? Then, you are done. Try this direction.

Comment: @астон Are you certain that will work, or is that a guess?

Comment: @BillDubuque It's a guess. The first thing that came in mind. I was just wondering if it was possible. I've had a close look, but it seems a bit difficult. Anyway, there is an answer below.

Comment: @астон  That's what I surmised, so it is good that you clarified that so that the OP doesn't end up on a wild goose chase.

Comment: @BillDubuque Yes, it absolutely does not work. Thank you for anyway surmising it, I was on a wild goose chase for some time too!

Answer (score 1):

**This is not correct!**

If $n$ is such that $\gcd(3^{n+1}-2,2^n-3)>1$, then there exists a prime $p$ such that $3^{n+1}=2\bmod p$ and $2^n=3\bmod p$. But this implies
$$3^{n+1}=(2^n)^{n+1}=2^{n^2+n}=2\bmod p,$$
hence $2^{n^2+n-1}=1\bmod p$, and hence $\varphi(p)=p-1$ divides $n^2+n-1$, **no, all we can conclude is $\gcd(p-1,n^2+n-1)>1$**. Considering the possibilities modulo 4 shows that this is not possible.

Elaboration on the mod 4 argument: If $p-1$ divides $n^2+n-1$ then
$$n^2+n-1=k(p-1)$$
for some integer $k$. Note that $p$ is odd since both $3^{n+1}-2$ and $2^n-3$ are odd. Thus $p=1,3\bmod 4$, so
$$k(p-1)=0,2\bmod 4.$$
On the other side, if $n$ is odd or $n=2\bmod 4$ then
$$n^2+n-1=1\bmod 4,$$
and if $n=0\bmod 4$ then
$$n^2+n-1=3\bmod 4.$$
Therefore $n^2+n-1\ne k(p-1)$, so $p-1$ does not divide $n^2+n-1$.

Comment: It would probably be helpful to many readers if you elaborated on the mod $4$ argument.

Comment: @BillDubuque Can you explain why $\varphi(p)$ divides $n^2+n-1$ here?

Comment: @user19405892 Only Heath can explain that, since no justification is given above. That's why I was nudging him to elaborate.

Comment: @user19405892 You have pointed out the fatal mistake in my argument. I made the assumption that $2$ is a primitive root mod $p$, which is certainly not necessarily true. I will leave the wrong answer here in case someone can patch this hole.

Comment: Heath, suggest a separate argument for when $3$ is a primitive root. Then whatever you can think of when neither one is a primitive root, rather some $r$ which will remain unspecified.

Comment: Now that I think of it, better to do primitive roots 2, 3, then 5, 7, before jumping to unspecified primitive root $r.$

Comment: @WillJagy To clarify your point for others, the case when 3 is a primitive root is handled identically by writing $3=2^n=(3^{n+1})^n\bmod p$. I fiddled with that idea for a little bit, but couldn't get any handle on it. Please write another answer if you manage it.

Comment: Heath, if we switch the $n, n+1,$ we get primes $23$ and $6263.$ If we revert to $n,n,$ we get primes $5$ and $5333.$ I don't have any example for the problem as stated, but it is beginning to seem an open problem.